# Java Card applet: How to create EFs,DFs in smart card?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I'm a newbie in Java Card development and I'm trying to develop an applet that can select and read EF data.
I would like to create EFs and DFs with some fake data and store it in the card. Then I would use my applet to read these data.
Is it possible? If so, how can I do that? 
Please help, I've searched a lot but I did not find any solution for that.

Many thanks.

Comment: What you want? A Link List file structure or Array List file structure?

Comment: I does not sound, as if you really want a javacard, since a native smart card is much closer. Also it is not typical, that an *applet* reads files Mostly this is done by the host application.

Comment: My purpose is create files system of java card. Data of these files system is defined by myself. Is any way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

In a time long gone there was a file system API for Java Card. That API however has been deprecated. That means that you have to implement a  proprietary version of `CREATE FILE` and the ISO versions of `READ BINARY` and `UPDATE BINARY` yourself. You may also want to implement `SELECT by ID` if you don't want to rely on implicit selection by SFI. These commands have been defined in the ISO/IEC 7816-4 standard (payware, but there is info availale online). You may want to constrain yourself to implementing "transparent" EF files which are just binary files as you are used to in your operating system.

Usually the files consist of an (object containing a) Java Card byte array in EEPROM (just `new byte[size]`) for the file and meta information - maybe also in a `byte[]`) such as read/write access conditions. This is fine unless you need over 32Ki of memory, in which case you require multiple byte arrays.

A DF may consist of EF's, objects such as keys, PIN's, access conditions. The applet itself is a named DF, but you can createa a specific `CREATE FILE` for creating DF's. You would of course have to support the DF selection as well within `SELECT by ID`. Furthermore, you should keep a reference to the currently selected DF **and** EF in transient memory.

Comment: I'd like to say that to my knowledge, there is no really good free java card implementation of a file system. It seems everybody just implements the minimum he needs but there is no "full" free implementation. Probably because less code is desirable

Comment: @PaulBastian And with good reason. ISO/IEC 7816-4 contains a lot of fluff you really don't need most of the time - if it is understood at all. It also contains a lot of uncertainty and blanks. I've never seen an application either that can be used by just implementing ISO 7816 standards - including file based cards. A base implementation would be nice though.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes, thank you very much, by the way could you give specific examples or links of any tutorial?